# Differences between mysqli and ibase syntax in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

New in PHP, i have things that i dont know. For example, I was looking for a solution while googling, then i came across a unique(unique for me) sql statement,

```
$q=ibase_query("select * from table");
$res=ibase_fetch_assoc($q);
```

I usually use mysqli syntax for these query. So, can anyone explain to me the differences between ibase and mysqli? and which is have more advantages between these two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Used for  Interbase Database (ibase_*). Its full-featured relational database that developers can embed into their software applications